# Xamarin iOS & Mac - Compiler crashed with code: 1

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

Suddenly all my Xamarin Projects stopped building with the above mention compile error. I also tried reinstalling XS and VS for Mac but nothing helped.

This is the Build-Output I get:

```
CustomDialogController.designer.cs(16,22): warning CS0114: 'CustomDialogController.Description' hides inherited member 'NSObject.Description'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
CustomDialogController.designer.cs(19,22): warning CS0114: 'CustomDialogController.Title' hides inherited member 'NSViewController.Title'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

    Unhandled Exception:
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in <ffb99659fc1c47faa4d5f883014d08aa>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.FullMetadataWriter+DefinitionIndex`1[T].get_Item (T item) [0x00000] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.FullMetadataWriter.GetMethodDefinitionHandle (Microsoft.Cci.IMethodDefinition def) [0x00007] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.SerializeMethodDebugInfo (Microsoft.Cci.IMethodBody bodyOpt, System.Int32 methodRid, System.Reflection.Metadata.StandaloneSignatureHandle localSignatureHandleOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.LocalVariableHandle& lastLocalVariableHandle, System.Reflection.Metadata.LocalConstantHandle& lastLocalConstantHandle) [0x0024d] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.SerializeMethodBodies (System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder ilBuilder, Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidStringFixup) [0x000d7] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.BuildMetadataAndIL (Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder ilBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder mappedFieldDataBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder managedResourceDataBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidFixup, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidStringFixup) [0x00032] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.PeWriter.WritePeToStream (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitContext context, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, System.Func`1[TResult] getPeStream, System.Func`1[TResult] getPortablePdbStreamOpt, Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.String pdbPathOpt, System.Boolean allowMissingMethodBodies, System.Boolean isDeterministic, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0004c] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.SerializeToPeStream (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.CommonPEModuleBuilder moduleBeingBuilt, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation+EmitStreamProvider peStreamProvider, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation+EmitStreamProvider pdbStreamProvider, System.Func`1[TResult] testSymWriterFactory, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag diagnostics, System.Boolean metadataOnly, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00120] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.RunCore (System.IO.TextWriter consoleOutput, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorLogger errorLogger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00475] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.Run (System.IO.TextWriter consoleOutput, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00035] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Run>b__0 (System.IO.TextWriter tw) [0x00000] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.ConsoleUtil.RunWithUtf8Output[T] (System.Boolean utf8Output, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, System.Func`2[T,TResult] func) [0x0001d] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc.Run (System.String[] args, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerLoader) [0x00048] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_int_string[]_BuildPaths_TextWriter_IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader (string[],Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths,System.IO.TextWriter,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.RunLocalCompilation (System.String[] arguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter) [0x00000] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildClient.RunCompilation (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] originalArguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter) [0x0009d] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.Run (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arguments, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] extraArguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.RequestLanguage language, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.CompileFunc compileFunc, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerAssemblyLoader) [0x0003e] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main (System.String[] args, System.String[] extraArgs) [0x00018] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in <ffb99659fc1c47faa4d5f883014d08aa>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.FullMetadataWriter+DefinitionIndex`1[T].get_Item (T item) [0x00000] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.FullMetadataWriter.GetMethodDefinitionHandle (Microsoft.Cci.IMethodDefinition def) [0x00007] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.SerializeMethodDebugInfo (Microsoft.Cci.IMethodBody bodyOpt, System.Int32 methodRid, System.Reflection.Metadata.StandaloneSignatureHandle localSignatureHandleOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.LocalVariableHandle& lastLocalVariableHandle, System.Reflection.Metadata.LocalConstantHandle& lastLocalConstantHandle) [0x0024d] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.SerializeMethodBodies (System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder ilBuilder, Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidStringFixup) [0x000d7] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.MetadataWriter.BuildMetadataAndIL (Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder ilBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder mappedFieldDataBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder managedResourceDataBuilder, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidFixup, System.Reflection.Metadata.Blob& mvidStringFixup) [0x00032] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.Cci.PeWriter.WritePeToStream (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitContext context, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, System.Func`1[TResult] getPeStream, System.Func`1[TResult] getPortablePdbStreamOpt, Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter nativePdbWriterOpt, System.String pdbPathOpt, System.Boolean allowMissingMethodBodies, System.Boolean isDeterministic, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0004c] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.SerializeToPeStream (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.CommonPEModuleBuilder moduleBeingBuilt, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation+EmitStreamProvider peStreamProvider, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation+EmitStreamProvider pdbStreamProvider, System.Func`1[TResult] testSymWriterFactory, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag diagnostics, System.Boolean metadataOnly, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00120] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.RunCore (System.IO.TextWriter consoleOutput, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorLogger errorLogger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00475] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.Run (System.IO.TextWriter consoleOutput, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00035] in <12d27e16f5684917a6cbffa8f9cc6eae>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Run>b__0 (System.IO.TextWriter tw) [0x00000] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.ConsoleUtil.RunWithUtf8Output[T] (System.Boolean utf8Output, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, System.Func`2[T,TResult] func) [0x0001d] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc.Run (System.String[] args, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerLoader) [0x00048] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_int_string[]_BuildPaths_TextWriter_IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader (string[],Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths,System.IO.TextWriter,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.RunLocalCompilation (System.String[] arguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter) [0x00000] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildClient.RunCompilation (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] originalArguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildPaths buildPaths, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter) [0x0009d] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.Run (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arguments, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] extraArguments, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.RequestLanguage language, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.CompileFunc compileFunc, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerAssemblyLoader) [0x0003e] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main (System.String[] args, System.String[] extraArgs) [0x00018] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <0b73f303db124699a9f415aa972a6e9f>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.
Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/Lama/Lama.Mac/Lama.Mac.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/Lama/Lama.Mac/Lama.Mac.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

     /Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/Lama/Lama.Mac/Lama.Mac.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Mac/Xamarin.Mac.Common.targets (_CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions target) ->

Main.storyboard: ibtool warning : Automatic preferred width mode for static wrapping text before OS X 10.11, use Explicit or First Runtime Layout Width
Main.storyboard: ibtool warning : Automatic preferred width mode for static wrapping text before OS X 10.11, use Explicit or First Runtime Layout Width
Main.storyboard: ibtool warning : Distribution before OS X 10.11
Main.storyboard: ibtool warning : Detaches Hidden Views before OS X 10.11
Main.storyboard: ibtool warning : “View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:]

/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/Lama/Lama.Mac/Lama.Mac.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

CustomDialogController.designer.cs(16,22): warning CS0114: 'CustomDialogController.Description' hides inherited member 'NSObject.Description'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
CustomDialogController.designer.cs(19,22): warning CS0114: 'CustomDialogController.Title' hides inherited member 'NSViewController.Title'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

Errors:

/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/Lama/Lama.Mac/Lama.Mac.csproj (Build) ->
 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.

 7 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Hopefully someone knows whats going wrong here and could help me out

Thanks!

Comment: There's a key missing from a dictionary somewhere in the compiler's code.
The stacktrace isn't that helpful, either, as it's ommitting the code files and line numbers.
Have you tried building the solution on Windows, using Visual Studio?
I've had some success with similar errors using that approach.

Comment: no actually I did not try that yet. But how could it be that suddenly a key is missing in every project? Or maybe this is caused by Xamarin updates?

Comment: It may very well be caused by Xamarin updates. Which channel are you using? Stable, beta, alpha?

Comment: Stable normally, the build still crashes after i completely reinstalled Xamarin, so this is the Stable Channel

Comment: I suggest trying to build on Windows, see if the issue persists. If so, it's an issue with the project and we can further dig down to see where the issue is. 
If it builds, it's an issue with Mono, in which case you may have to delete the entire framework and its downloaded files from your Mac.

Comment: I had an other idea to download an older version of the mono framework [here](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/4.8.1/macos-10-universal/) and it builds just fine

Comment: As long as it helped! You may want to add that as an answer so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

After trying a little I found out that installing a lower version of the [Mono Framework](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/4.8.1/macos-10-universal/) did help. Try a version lower 5.0